# Is it REST if I pass the following URI /apps/{id}?control=start

Tags: api, rest, modeling

I'm in the process of designing a REST API for our web app.

POST > /apps             > Creates an app
PUT  > /apps/{id}        > Updates the app

I want to start the apps. 
Is this REST and if not, how can I make it more RESTful?

1. POST > /apps/{id}?control=start

Sun Cloud API does this: http://kenai.com/projects/suncloudapis/pages/CloudAPISpecificationResourceModels

Or is it better to:
2. PUT /apps/{id} and include a status parameter in the response Json/XML?
3. POST /apps/{id} and include a status parameter in the response Json/xml?

4. POST /apps/start?app={id}

Answer (score 2):

I think the right question here is more whether the HTTP verbs are being used as intended rather than whether the application is or is not as RESTful as possible.  However, these days the two concepts are pretty much the same.

The thing about `PUT` is that whatever you `PUT` you should be able to immediately `GET`.  In other words, `PUT` does a wholesale replacement of the resource.  If the resource stored at `apps/5` is something that has a "control" attribute as part of its state, then the control=start part should be part of the representation you put.  If you want to send just the new piece of the resource, you are doing a PATCH, not a PUT.

PATCH is not widely supported, so IMHO you should use a POST.  POST has no requirements of safety or idempotency; generally you can do whatever you want with a POST (more or less), including patching parts of a resource.  After all that is what you do when you create a new item in a collection with a POST.  Updating a portion of a resource is not really much different.

Generally though you POST new data in the request body, not as query parameters.  Query parameters are used mostly for GETs, because you are, well, querying. :)

Comment: Ray you are saying that ?control=start is a query parameter and should not be used with POST?

Comment: The technical term for the parameters that follow the `?` in a URL is indeed "query parameter."  They are generally used in GETs to restrict the collection of object returned such as in `GET /apps?author=Samad&platform=ios` which would return the collections of all iPhone apps authored by you. :)  See how that is different from `GET /apps' which returns all apps and `GET /apps/5` which returns the single app with id=5.  You _can_ use query parameters with POST (no one will stop you), but the _convention_ in HTTP is to POST data within entity bodies.  It's just more in line with what POST is.

Answer (score 2):

Does starting an app changes it state? (to "running", for example) If it does what you're actually doing is updating the state of the resource (application). That seems like a good use for the `PUT` operation. Although as Ray said, if control is part of the state of the resource, the body of the `PUT` request should contain the state you're updating. I believe a partial update would be possible (CouchDB uses this).

On the other hand, if starting an app means creating a new resource (representing the app execution, for example), the `POST` method would be a great fit. You could have something like this:

```
POST /app/1/start
```

Which would result in a `HTTP/1.1 201 Created`. Then, to access the information on the created execution, you could use a URL like this:

```
GET /app/1/execution/1
```

To me, this would seem like a good "Restful" approach. For more information, check out this [article](http://www.infoq.com/articles/subbu-allamaraju-rest).

Answer (score 1):

`PUT apps/{id}`

I would PUT the app to update it's status from `off` to `on`

Answer (score -1):

I like to do something like,

```
POST /runningapps?url=/app/1
```